# Can not creat tables from entities. JTA and Glassfish

Tags: jpa, glassfish, eclipselink, jta

I have a question about JTA with Glassfish. For days Iam trying to solve this problem. I want to write an Entity in a database. To keep it simple I use the GlassfishDB. In the Glassfish-Admin Console I use the

> jdbc/__default

as Resource. The Ping of the Connection-Pool is working. In the persistence.xml I have declared that Iam using JTA and that jdbc/__ default is my Resource. If I try to create tables from fields I get an Exception:

```
[EL Info]: EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600
java.lang.NullPointerException
at `enter code here`com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getRemoteProvider(SerialContext.java:297)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:271)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:430)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:569)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:415)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:110)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:94)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:584)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:228)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:369)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getServerSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:151)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:207)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:195)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.perform(Main.java:85)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.execute(Main.java:76)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.main(Main.java:63)
[EL Severe]: Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600):           
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [jdbc/__default].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/__default' in   
SerialContext  [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire   
SerialContextProvider for SerialContext  [Root exception is   
java.lang.NullPointerException]]
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.cannotAcquireDataSource(ValidationException.java:451)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:116)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:94)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:584)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:228)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:369)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getServerSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:151)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:207)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:195)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.perform(Main.java:85)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.execute(Main.java:76)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.main(Main.java:63)
 Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/__default' in    
 SerialContext  [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire      
 SerialContextProvider for SerialContext  [Root exception is  
 java.lang.NullPointerException]]
```

The persistence.xml is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"   
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence   
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="Test" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/__default</jta-data-source>
 </persistence-unit>
   </persistence>
```

The `<resources>`-part of the domain.xml of Glassfish is:

```
-<resources> 
  <jdbc-resource object-type="system-admin" jndi-name="jdbc/__TimerPool" pool-  
  name="__TimerPool"/> 
  <jdbc-resource jndi-name="jdbc/__default" pool-name="DerbyPool"/> 
 -<jdbc-connection-pool name="__TimerPool" res-type="javax.sql.XADataSource"  
   datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedXADataSource"> 
  <property name="databaseName"   
   value="${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/lib/databases/ejbtimer"/> 
  <property name="connectionAttributes" value=";create=true"/> 
  </jdbc-connection-pool>  
  -<jdbc-connection-pool name="DerbyPool" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" datasource- 
   classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource" is-isolation-level-
   guaranteed="false"> <property name="PortNumber" value="1527"/> 
   <property name="Password" value="APP"/> 
   <property name="User" value="APP"/> <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>  
   <property name="DatabaseName" value="sun-appserv-samples"/> 
   <property name="connectionAttributes" value=";create=true"/> 
   </jdbc-connection-pool> 
   -<jdbc-connection-pool name="PostSQLPool" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource"  
    datasource-classname="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource" ping="true"> 
   <property name="databaseName" value="PostSQLDatenbank"/> 
   <property name="password" value="philipp"/> <property name="portNumber" 
   value="5432"/> 
   <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/> 
   <property name="user" value="postgres"/> 
   <property name="URL" value="URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Time"/> 
   </jdbc-connection-pool> -
   <jdbc-connection-pool name="PostPool" res-
   type="javax.sql.DataSource" datasource- 
   classname="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource" ping="true"> 
   <property name="Url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/PostSQLDatenbank"/> 
   <property name="URL" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/PostSQLDatenbank"/>  
   <property name="databaseName" value="PostSQLDatenbank"/> 
   <property name="password" value="philipp"/> 
   <property name="portNumber" value="5432"/> 
   <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/> 
   <property name="user" value="postgres"/> 
   </jdbc-connection-pool> 
 </resources>
```

Comment: Could be an editing issue, but the persistence.xml shows two _ "__default" while you mention you defined "dbc/_default" as the resource.   They must match or it cannot be found

Comment: Hi, the one underscore instead of two was a problem of displaying it in the textarea. I changed the text to make it clear. I didn't change anything on the jdbc/__default, the GlassfishDB is connected, the classpath to the DB is set.

Comment: Is `jdbc/__default` the connection pool name or the JDBC resource one? It must be the latter

Comment: Can you attach the `<resources>` section of the `domain.xml` glassfish configuration file?

Comment: I added the <resources> part of the domain.xml. jdbc/__default is the JDBC resource name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your stack trace it seems you are running outside of Glassfish, to use a Glassfish DataSource you need to be running inside the server.

If you want to run outside of Glassfish you need to specify the JDBC connection URL directly.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Runtime#Java_Standard_Edition

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. You were right, I had mixed something up in the ManagedBean. I used an EntityManagerFactory and an EntityManager, and the EntityManager wasn't annotated right. I deleted the EntityMFactory, but still it isn't working. To make sure, I didn't forget something here the steps I did: 1. ManagedBean with EntityManager and UserTranscaction. 2. Entity-Class 3. Started the DerbyDB 4. The Ping in the Glassfish-Admin Console works. 5. In the persistence.xml I used the JNDI-Resource jdbc/__default, and enabled JTA.         What am I doing wrong? Did I forget something?